# Insert missing values in Sharepoint Online usning Azure Logic App

Tags: sql-server, azure, sharepoint-online, azure-logic-apps

I've a SQL Server table with a column **Manufacturer** with 4 rows:

```
Integral Coach Factor
Bharat Heavy Electricals Limited
Chittaranjan Locomotive Works
Golden Work Railway Workshop
```

Same data is available in a Sharepoint List as well:

```
Integral Coach Factor
Bharat Heavy Electricals Limited
Golden Work Railway Workshop
```

My task is to run a logic app every 24 hours and insert the missing values in the Sharepoint list. For the above example, I would need to insert only **Chittaranjan Locomotive Works** in the sharepoint as it is missing in the sharepoint list.

I'm new to Azure Logic App, and need some help to accomplish the task.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sharepoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, please refer to my logic app shown as below:

**1.** Now I have a table shown like:
[image]

**2.** Go to logic app, use "[Get rows(V2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sql/#get-rows-(v2))" action to get rows of the table.
[image]

**3.** Then use "[Get items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepoint/#get-items)" action to get all of the items in your sharepoint list.
[image]

**4.** Use "[Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#select-action)" action to select the "**Title**" of each item of the sharepoint list. And input "**Manufacturer**" as "key" of each "Title".
[image]

**5.** After that, use "[For each](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops#foreach-loop)" to loop the value from "**Get rows(V2)**".
[image]

**6.** In "For each" loop, add a "[Compose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#compose-action)" action with content like below:
[image]

**7.** After the "**Compose**", add a "[Condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-conditional-statement#add-condition)" to judge if it exists in sharepoint list. Choose `Output` of "**Select**" action as content of first input box and choose `Output` of "**Compose**" action as content of second input box.
[image]

**8.** If "false", create item with current "Manufacturer" as its "Title".
[image]

Comment: Perfect Hury. Thanks a lot.